# Error "Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json or one of its dependencies" occurs every day

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, fileloadexception

I get the following error every day:

```
Exception information: 
Exception type: FileLoadException 
Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I can temporarily fix it by renaming the dll and then reverting the rename. I've check the web config for the proper assembly redirect:

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
```

I have also checked the file assembly version number and that is 4.5.0.0
It's version 5.0.8 of the Newtonsoft.Json package.

[image]

How is it possible that this error keeps occurring everyday? What are the possible causes?

**This problem seems to be fixed now. I manually cleaned the entire solution locally and also on the webserver. And did a clean deployment.**

Comment: Maybe you have a backup system that is locking the file at the same time you're program is trying to load it?

Comment: It's always the same dll of the same website. If this was the case i'd expect other dll's or other projects to show similair errors.

Comment: "4.5.0.0 It's version 5.0.8 of the Newtonsoft.Json package" - this statement feels wrong. Usually version of Newtonsoft.Json matches version of NuGet... Usually the wrong version is brought in by System.Web.Http assembly - check out if you use it.

Comment: I've added a picture of the version information. Newtonsoft.Json used the targeted .net version of it's dll as the assembly version I believe.

I do use System.Web.Http. But a request to the wrong version should be redirected by the bindingRedirect in the web.config. Also I expect that the website would never work if this was the problem.

Comment: Is another component using a newer version of Newtonsoft.Json? Is any Newtonsoft.Json in the GAC (probably not what you want)? Renaming a .dll will force an application pool recycle, might be a clue as well.

Comment: I've checked the GAC using gacutil. It finds no assemblies.

If a recycle of this website 'fixes' it, could a recycle of another website that uses a different version break it?

Comment: No, that shouldn't fix it (the app recycle on a different website) as they are seperate, and no NewtonSoft library is found in the GAC. Maybe somewhere in the code you're loading a previous version? Also: could you perhaps post all your assembly redirects?

Comment: I suspect I didn't deploy the website correctly leaving some old dll's in place that caused a conflict. I did a major update of the website and then rolled it back because of an error. I think something was left behind that should have been deleted.